# Appcrash Kernelbase.dll error when attempting to run SSIS package via DTExec.exe

Tags: sql-server, ssis, 32bit-64bit, crash, dtexec

I recently came across an issue while attempting to run a master parent SSIS package which calls several children packages. I haven't found a post with this exact issue, so I thought I'd share how I believe to have solved the issue. This is the error that would occur when attempting to run the package:

[image]

So after researching the issue, I believe what the cause was, was that I was attempting to run the SSIS package on a 64 bit server in one of our lower environments, and a few of the children packages called by the master parent package would read from MS Access database files, which were 32 bits. So in order to resolve this issue, I found this site very helpful:

- [SSIS Executing Packages](http://oakdome.com/programming/SSIS_ExecutingPackages.php)

...from where I realized that I needed to include an "/x86" switch in the .bat file which was calling my Master package to run, like so:

*REM Runs DTSX package via the command line*

```
pushd D:\SFAS\SSIS\SESDatamart\bin
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" **/x86** /f "D:\SFAS\SSIS\SESDatamart\packages\MASTER DATAMART.dtsx" /set "\package.variables[User::PriorYears].Properties[Value]";3 
popd
```

*REM Capture error code and send to UC4*

```
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

In any case, I wanted to post this somewhere, so that it might help someone who might be experiencing this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to provide an update to this error. It turns out that it wasn't only a matter of adding the "X86" switch to the bat file, but that the Dev and Int servers were actually low on memory and processors. We ended up having to add additional of both and it seems to have resolved the issue, thankfully, by providing additional resources and processing power.